# Convert non-persisted Docker volume into persisted volume

Tags: docker

I have a busybox container to hold a MongoDb container data:

```
mongodb_data:
restart: always
container_name: mongodb_data
image: busybox:latest
command: echo created
volumes:
  - /data/db
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-file: "2"
        max-size: "5m"

  mongodb:
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
      - "27017"
    volumes_from:
      - mongodb_data
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: "2"
            max-size: "5m"
```

If I recreate the mongodb_data then all DB goes away therefore I would like to change the part of the volume definition to:

```
volumes:
  - ./myfolder:/data/db
```

That however does not seem to work. I don't know how to "copy" from the container to that folder and make the container use the actual folder to have that volume set up correctly. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: You don't use a container to hold data of another container. That's not how containers are intended to be used. Just use the `volumes` you mentioned later in your question with the `mongo` container and it'll copy the data in there.

Comment: You are right, however it looks like the content of that folder does not seem to be copied over from the container to the host. Should the map be that way? I don't want an empty folder to be mapped to /data/db if that makes sense

Comment: @msrumon Before Docker named volumes existed "data-only containers" were actually a thing and I wouldn't be surprised to find references to them around the Internet (they still show up in very old SO answers).  This setup feels archaic to me, but it was a best practice at one point.

Comment: You should be able to `docker-compose cp mongodb_data:/data/db ./myfolder`.  `docker cp` doesn't particularly care that the container directory holds an anonymous volume.  I've linked this to a question that describes the setup further.

Comment: I was able to do it from the mongodb_data container and simplified the docker-compose. Thanks for this. It now makes much more sense